# Нарушение в описании последовательности событий?

Tags: согласование, деепричастия

**Ванька сунул веточку в муравейник, наблюдая, как засуетились муравьи.**

События идут так: Ванька засовывает веточку в муравейник, после чего муравьи начинают суетиться.
Однако деепричастие *"наблюдая"*, поскольку им обозначено протяжённое во времени действие, относится не только к моменту начала муравьиной суеты, но и к моменту сования веточки в муравейник, когда суеты ещё не было. Предложение говорит нам, что Ванька, когда совал палочку, якобы *уже наблюдал, как засуетились муравьи*. Но это нарушает причинно-следственную связь. Получается, конструкция сбоит в плане описания последовательности событий.
Как полагаете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ванька сунул веточку в муравейник*, (одновременно) **наблюдая, как** (начали суетиться) **засуетились муравьи.**

1. Итак, Ванька подошел к муравейнику и начал за ним наблюдать. Потом сунул палку, не прекращая наблюдения. Муравьи, естественно, засуетились.

**Реальная последовательность действий:** наблюдает за муравьями, сует палку, муравьи начали суетиться. Всё нормально.

2. Для большей ясности можно записать так: *Ванька сунул веточку в муравейник, наблюдая **при этом**, как засуетились муравьи.*

Подобная проблема рассматривается у Розенталя:

[http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#з_02](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm#%D0%B7_02)

...преимуществом придаточных предложений является наличие в них союзов, придающих высказыванию различные оттенки значения, которые теряются при замене придаточного предложения деепричастным оборотом. Ср.: **когда** он вошел..., **после того как** он вошел..., **как только** он вошел..., едва он вошел... и т.п. и синонимический вариант войдя, указывающий только на предшествующее действие, но лишенный **тонких оттенков временного значения**.

При использовании деепричастного оборота в подобных случаях следует потерю союза **восполнять, где это необходимо, лексическими средствами**, например, войдя... он сразу же (тотчас же, немедленно и т.п.).

Comment: Спасибо. Я всё планирую прочитать этот справочник Розенталя целиком, но руки не доходят.

Answer (score 1):

«Ванька сунул веточку в муравейник и стал (начал) наблюдать, как засуетились муравьи». Вот и весь сказ... А то, что сбоит, это есть такое...

Comment: Спасибо, это я знаю :) Меня интересует разбор именно моего случая. // Ваш вариант тоже не годится: "стал наблюдать" — протяжённое во времени действие, "засуетились" — одномоментное. Если править предложение, то примерно так: "Ванька сунул веточку в муравейник и стал наблюдать за засуетившимися муравьями". (Это плохо, потому что за-за, но как пример сойдёт.)

Comment: «Ванька сунул веточку в муравейник и стал наблюдать, как муравьи начали суетиться»?

Comment: Здесь та же история: 'стал наблюдать' - длительное действие, 'начали суетиться' - одномоментное событие.

Comment: «Ванька сунул веточку в муравейник и стал наблюдать за засуетившимися муравьями. Ваш вариант. Получается, муравьи уже засуетились, как он сунул веточку.... прям в один миг... Время должно пройти некоторое, прежде чем они засуетятся... и поймут, что кто-то сует палку в их домик...

Comment: 'И' создаёт некий 'буфер времени'. 'Я бросил жрать фастфуд и похудел' - не одномоментно же.

Comment: Пока Вы писали «И», муравьи успели засуетиться....

Comment: Я же привёл пример. В "буфере времени" может заключаться длительный период. 'Я сел в поезд и приехал в Москву'.

Comment: А как Вам такое: «Ванька сунул веточку в муравейник и увидел, как засуетились муравьи»?!

Comment: Это нормально, но тут немного искажается смысл, всё-таки увидеть и наблюдать — вещи разные.

Answer (score -1):

Действительно есть сбой в последовательности событий. Если Ванька и наблюдал изначально, то не за тем, как суетятся муравьи, а за их спокойной рутиной. Поэтому деепричастие употреблено неверно. Корректный вариант, на мой взгляд:

> Ванька сунул веточку в муравейник, пронаблюдав, как засуетились
> муравьи.

Значение деепричастия "пронаблюдав": "наблюдая, увидеть все этапы развития, осуществления чего-либо".

Comment: Вот и я так полагаю. А мне со всех сторон говорят, что всё нормально. Я, однако, останусь при своём.

Comment: За тех, кто так говорит, отвечать не берусь. На мой взгляд, всё однозначно и вы правы

Comment: Действие (наблюдение) ЗАКОНЧИЛОСЬ...  А в заданном предложении оно ПРОДОЛЖАЕТСЯ.  Это все видят? Наш язык удивительный, его надо просто слушать, а также очень желательно избегать поспешных, формальных и однозначных суждений. Мы не пользуемся СЛОЖНОЙ СИСТЕМОЙ ВРЕМЕН, которая есть в других языках. Но наши глагольные формы позволяют выразить все нужные смысловые оттенки, в частности для этого  дополнительно применяется лексика (временные наречия и другие слова). С категорией времени связаны морфемы – так приставка ЗА может обозначать как начало, так и конец действия.